# function that has an ajax events return undefined when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function called 'getAuthor' and inside there's an ajax events running (refer below)

```
function getAuthor(id){
    $.get('http://www.connectnigeria.com/articles/wp-json/wp/v2/users/74',function(e){
        var author = e.name;
        console.log(author);
        return author;
    });
}
```

try to run from the console, you'll see it returns "undefined" while console.log display the expected response from the ajax call.

Any, ideas help please?

Comment: see this : [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You are trying to return the author inside the anonymous function. Not from getAuthor function

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a explicit return from a function , it will always return `undefined`.

In console it is undefined because the function `getAuthor` is not returning anything. Not to be confused with the return from `$.get`.

The `console.log` statement is inside this asynchronous function. To get a return from the function `getAuthor` try this

```
function getAuthor(id){
    return $.get('http://www.connectnigeria.com/articles/wp-json/wp/v2/users/74',function(e){
        var author = e.name;
        console.log(author);
        return author;
    });
}
```